# Which image viewer from Ubuntu repositories supports image auto rotate based on EXIF?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, image-processing, photo-management, image-viewers

I have used Fastone Image Viewer on MS Windows for long time.

One of its great features was image auto-rotation based on EXIF attributes.
So viewer rotates image to show it in correct orientation.

Which image viewer should I use on Ubuntu to get this functionality?

Comment: Do you want images to be *displayed* rotated according to Exif tags? Or do you want files to be *modified* with rotation according to Exif tags? Probably most available image viewers can rotate for display. I use `geeqie`.

Comment: @xiota I want files to be displayed with correct rotation.

Comment: I don't know of any image viewer on Ubuntu that is not supporting that.

Comment: The Answer to questions similar to *Which image viewer supports XYZ* is almost always **Geeqie**.